# If a transposed convolution layer takes in a 3 channel input and gives out a 2 channel output, how many kernels would it have and why?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Isn't the tconv layer supposed to have 6 kernels divided into two? One three kernels for one channel, another three kernels for another channel making two channels because the tconv layer is to give out a two channel output? I'm I right or what?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's how it works. It's explained in the [Conv2d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) documentation, you can see it by printing the shape of the weight tensor :

```
import torch.nn as nn
x = nn.Conv2d(3, 2, 7)
print(x.weight.shape)
>>> (2, 3, 7, 7)
```

There are indeed 2 groups of 3 kernels of shape (7,7)

Comment: I'm talking about a transposed convolution layer not a convolution layer. The weight shape is different for a transposed convolution layer and I don't know why that is. If you know please tell me.